# Generate SSDeep in java 8

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-8, virus

I want to generate the ssdeep like https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload since a file.

But I try with those dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.debatty</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-spamsum</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
    </dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.bl.wa.bitwiser</groupId>
        <artifactId>bitwiser</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

any of them give me the same ssdeep as virustotal.
for exemple the same file :

virusTotal : 
SSDEEP  3072:m1b1pWIwmYWTnZq0JzO0ix8vYABJ8Yqplrkvo2IRbIMbkaEcp2kr67xP9:UxV/TnVJnix8waKYkGo2aOcp2kr6Nl

Bitwiser :

SSDeep":"6144:kI9pgt+0CpujqDTW44Ni2ENbIX/b3Lc/g:atzCpgqERENUXj3v

Spamsum:

SSDeep":"6144:d40lK040lKQneE0sNhJAyUwLQWwZ211gMOzSChs1uCt+FXS:dJK0JKQebsNh/UXWz+XzS8s1uCn

could you give me some help ? I don't know really standard ssdeep is ...

explain me why ?

Thank you.

```
  public static String getHashSSDeepWithBitwiser(File fileToHash) throws IOException {
    SSDeep ssd = new SSDeep();
    FuzzyHash h = ssd.fuzzy_hash_file(fileToHash);
    return h.getBlocksize() + ":" + h.getHash() + ":" + h.getHash2();

}

public static String getHashSSDeepWithSpamSum(File fileToHash) {
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(fileToHash, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    SpamSum s = new SpamSum();
    s.HashString(content);
    return s.toString();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for SpamSum library? I don't think any of what you have written is related to Symantect or an antivirus for that matter. Take a look here: https://github.com/tdebatty/java-spamsum

Comment: Sorry, it's mistake with dependency Symantect. I changed my dependency by bitwiser